# Enable Einstein Forecasting

Tags: einstein-analytics, forecast, forecasts-collaborative

I have recently started working on **Einstein Forecasting**. How much time does it takes to enable Einstein Forecasting? I have enabled it 4 days ago, but still I can see that the **Einstein Forecasting Analytics App** is being installed.[image]

Comment: Are you able to see 'reconfigure app' under the 'Einstein Forecasting' tab? If so, can you perform this action and see if it fixes the issue?

Comment: Hey Swetha, I am not able to see this option.